# Wildfly Swarm write to external database

Tags: database, h2, wildfly-swarm

Is there any way to bypass the internal h2 database and connect wildfly swarm to an external database so that changes aren't lost after restarting the application server?

I read several tutorials, but the use of container is already deprecated.

I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to use a different database other than H2 is described here: https://wildfly-swarm.gitbooks.io/wildfly-swarm-users-guide/content/common/jpa.html

Though `Container` is deprecated, the replacement for it in a custom `main()` is just `Swarm`.

Comment: Thanks. I included the h2 dependency and I am now starting a h2 tcp server programatically in the Main class. Then I am connecting according to your referenced user guide!